# void* is not a pointer to object type - Casting error from void**

Tags: c++, data-structures, casting, void-pointers

I've got a function Quit that is receiving a void** and I need to pass it to a new function who's receiving a DataStructure*.

The problem is that the data in ds is replaced with garbage. What can I do ?

```
void Quit(void** DS){
       DataStructure* ds = (DataStructure*) *DS;
       return ds->Quit(); //'void*' is not a pointer to object type
}
```

when the definition of the second Quit() is:

```
void DataStructure::Quit();
```

and the call in main is done as follow:

```
DataStructure *data;
Quit((void**) &ds);
```

We get the same result if we cast as follow:

```
 DataStructure* ds = reinterpret_cast<DataStructure*>(*DS);
```

Comment: `((DataStructure*)* DS);` looks like a NOP.

Comment: you need to provide full compile error and/or complete example

Comment: If `data` doesn't point to a valid `DataStructure`, you can't expect anything to work.

Answer (score 2):

The cast works, it just doesn't change the type of `DS` like you expect it to do.

`((DataStructure*)* DS)` converts the value of `*DS` and throws the result away.
(Your compiler might have warned you that it has no effect.)

You need to save the result of the conversion:

```
void Quit(void** DS){
       DataStructure* ds = (DataStructure*) *DS;
       return ds->Quit();
}
```

Comment: or better yer, `DataStructure* ds = reinterpret_cast<DataStructure*>(*DS);`

Comment: It pass the compilation but I lose what was in DS (for every answer). I don't want to lose that data. Indeed, DS is of a DataStructure** type but my function get only void**.

Comment: @R.Gad Post the code that creates this `void**` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your `DS` variable actually is a `DataStructure*` you can simply cast it:

```
void Quit(void** DS)
{
       DataStructure* ds = (DataStructure*)DS;
       return ds->Quit();
}
```